# javascript - if(categories !== []) also returns empty arrays

Tags: javascript

I have a filter function to map trough some data. Then I want to check if some data remains after filtering and log the results. For some reason I am also getting empty arrays in my output.

```
// Filter categories
let categories = sport.Category.filter(filterById('a', 'b'));
sport.Category = categories;
// If category was found
if(categories !== []) {
    console.log(util.inspect(categories, false, null));
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Test the `length` property...

Comment: That's not doing what you think it's doing. You're comparing if the object is literally _not_ a different object. This check will _always_ pass because none of the objects are the same object as the one you just constructed for the `if` statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the length of the array not that it's the same as empty array. Checking it like you do, is not accurate and will fail at the cases where the categories array will have some "metadata" added.

```
// Filter categories
let categories = sport.Category.filter(filterById('a', 'b'));
sport.Category = categories;
// If category was found
if(categories.length > 0) {
    console.log(util.inspect(categories, false, null));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
if(categories.length > 0)
```

Comment: Or just __`if(categories.length)`__

Comment: yes :) I usually tend to prefer explicit code.. but this is a very trivial case. thanks!